# How to do variadic template for even position in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have to write a variadic template function that returns true if the value of every even position is lower than the value of the parameter on the next position.
Example:
f(4, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4) -> true (4 < 5, 7 < 9, 2 < 4)

i tried this :

```
template<typename T>
T check()
{
    auto even_number = [](T x)
    {  return (x % 2) == 0 ? x : 0; };
}

template <typename T, typename... A>
bool check(T first, A... args)
{
    return first < check(args...) ? true : false;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << check(4, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4);
}
```

and this program give me those errors :
1.'check' : no matching overloaded function found
2.'T check(void)': could not deduce template argument for T -> this error apear if ar second template I add "T check(T first, A... args)"

Comment: "even value" or "even position" ?

Comment: position, I will edit :)

Comment: Is the number of arguments guaranteed to be even?

Comment: I don't understand the question .I can have any arguments, only the position of each matters(to be even )

Comment: What happens if you do `check(1, 2, 3)`? `1 < 2` and `3 < ?`? And what happens if we do `check(1)`?

Comment: Hmm, i didn't thought of this :( you are right about the even number of parameters and for check(1) maybe just print 1 .

Comment: @loveProgram with the given solution, if you pass an odd total number of inputs the program won't compile.

Comment: I cannot make it work with event number of arguments :( i do something wrong but i don't know what, i tried to do it recursive.So how to check for what you two told me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Ints>
constexpr bool check( Ints... args)  requires(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Ints...>, int> && sizeof... (Ints) %2 == 0)
{
    int arr[] {args...};
    for(size_t i{}; i < sizeof... (args)/2; ++i){
        if (!(arr[2*i] < arr[2*i + 1])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << check(4, 3, 7, 9, 2, 4);
}
```

`requires(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Ints...>> && sizeof... (Ints) %2 == 0)` makes sure that the number of inputs is even and they are integers

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s5Kxfa)

---

A recursive version

```
template <typename Int, typename ... Ints>
constexpr bool check(Int int1,Int int2, Ints... ints)requires(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Int, Ints...>, int> && sizeof... (Ints) %2 == 0)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof... (Ints) == 0) return int1 < int2;
    else return int1 < int2 && (check(ints...));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E75e9P)

Comment: thank you for your response, but it's a way to do it recursive ?

Comment: if constexpr (sizeof... (Ints) == 0) return int1 < int2; i dont understand this .

Comment: @loveProgram this is the base case. If the inputs total number is 2, this line executes. if they are more the recursive line executes.

Comment: if i want to check the number of args to be even , not using what you did above , how to do it ? i tried this : " bool check(T x, T y, A... args)
{ if (sizeof... (A) % 2 == 0)
    {
        return x < y&& check(args...);
    } and this error apear " 'check' function doesnt take 1 arg

Comment: @loveProgram pass an even number of inputs to try your version.

Comment: if i erase it it work, but i wanted to know if it is another way to check it ,different from how you did .Because if this i tried to write in this way

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the number of arguments is always even, you can do it simply like this:

```
bool check() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
bool check(T t1, T t2, Ts... ts) {
    return t1 < t2 && (check(ts...));
}
```

Comment: but where to check for a argument that is on even position ? I check if a value that is on even position is < than the next value .

Comment: Why would you want to check for that? First argument is first, second is second. You take them by pairs.

Comment: and why did you put " && " ,can you explain me,please ?

Comment: This is a binary `and` operator. First we check whether the first two arguments match the `<` relation and then we say that we *also* need all of the following pairs to meet this requirement.

Comment: Thank you and one more question : why "bool check() {
    return true;
}"

Comment: Because `check(ts...)` means *call `check` with whatever is left in `ts...`. `ts...` **may be empty** and **will be empty** when we are done comparing all the pairs. When it's empty, it's effectively a call to `check()` (zero parameters). We need an overload to take care of that. If we didn't the only one would be our primary one: `bool check(T t1, T t2, Ts... ts)`. This expects **at least two parameters**. ( An alternative would be to use `if constexpr` with `sizeof...`, like in [asmmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875890/7151494).